# Maintaining mysql db and server loads

Tags: mysql

I am creating a chart using information from mysql. The problem is, the load on the database is huge and when you have hundreds or more people accessing the chart at the same time, MASSIVE stalling issues arise.

The queries look like the two I have listed below:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
                    FROM stream_updates 
                        INNER JOIN members 
                    ON members.username=stream_updates.username 
                    WHERE (stream_updates.time between (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW())
                    AND (members.username = :user) OR members.username IN (
                           SELECT friend2 as username FROM list_friends 
                           WHERE (friend1 = :user AND friend2 <> :user) 
                              UNION
                           SELECT friend1 as username FROM list_friends
                           WHERE (friend2 = :user AND friend1 <> :user)
                    )");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$textcnt1 = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
                    FROM stream_updates 
                        INNER JOIN members 
                    ON members.username=stream_updates.username 
                    WHERE (stream_updates.time between (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                    AND (members.username = :user) OR members.username IN (
                           SELECT friend2 as username FROM list_friends 
                           WHERE (friend1 = :user AND friend2 <> :user) 
                              UNION
                           SELECT friend1 as username FROM list_friends
                           WHERE (friend2 = :user AND friend1 <> :user)
                    )");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$textcnt2 = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

So the way it works is simple, 7 queries grab 7 different numbers based on the times they were posted. Each of those 7 queries is run against 5 different databases to make for the total of 35 queries. And this is only for a single chart on the page that is also performing other queries and doing other tasks.

I was thinking perhaps I could store the query values as cookies that expire every 30 minutes so as to lighten the load a touch, but was hoping others with more experience could perhaps offer some insight into how to do this?

The time and username columns are indexed and I am not looking to use stored procedures.

Is there a better way to do this so I don't make 35 separate database queries?

**UPDATED WITH AN SQL FIDDLE**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa369f6/1

The above fiddle only shows one example query. Simply switch to test various queries.

```
(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW())
```

to

```
(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

**Clarifying the queries**

So what these query do is simple. Each does a count for all rows matching a given user on a given table and based on that users friends.

In the sqlfiddle example, the return is 3 because a count of all posts in the "favorites" table matched again both a user and all their friends from table list_friends return 3. If we add another user to the table, but do no include said user in the friends list, those posts would not be counted.

All this works as expected, but 35 queries seems to have a rather large load even when they are indexed columns.

```
id   |     select_type     |    table     |  type   |  possible_keys  |   key    |  key_len  |        ref         |  rows  |  Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |       PRIMARY       |  favorites   |   ALL   |      NULL       |   NULL   |  NULL     |         NULL       |    9   |   
1    |       PRIMARY       |    members   |  eq_ref |    username     | username |    257    | favorites.username |    1   | Using where; Using index
2    | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  | list_friends |   ALL   |      NULL       |   NULL   |    NULL   |        NULL        |    3   |    Using where
3    |   DEPENDENT UNION   | list_friends |   ALL   |      NULL       |   NULL   |    NULL   |        NULL        |    3   |    Using where
NULL |    UNION RESULT     |  <union2,3>  |   ALL   |      NULL       |   NULL   |    NULL   |        NULL        |  NULL  |
```

Comment: @e4c5 I will update the question with tables and samples as soon as I can write out all the creations and data. It may take me an hour or so but I will update it. I avoid asking mysql questions for this reason.

Comment: Bruce, please see `Section 2 / What does Show your Schema Mean?` on my answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) . A data load may not be necessary depending on your questions. The top half of that, SqlFiddle, will make people quite happy in general when you post `mysql` questions.

Comment: I realized to use sql fiddle @Drew however I am not so fluent that I can just write my sql on the fly. I have to go back and forth and look at data types and table names and column names and lookup code to remember the create table formats... etc.

Comment: @e4c5 updated with a fiddle.

Comment: @bruce just like the rest of us. Yeah a question with a fiddle. Auto up vote

Comment: Also as per @e4c5 's request I explained the queries and the output a bit.

Comment: You can run these SQL and output result to a cache at every eg 10 minutes. All web visitors will call that cache instead of direct SQL call. so that you can benefit from cost.

Comment: @SIDU the problem is, each users requests will be different as each users requests are based off their own friends list.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to try to explain that a touch better.

Comment: If each SQL is different based on visitor, you can run some SQL and output to cache/temp_table at eg 10 minutes, and each visitor will run SQL against cache/temp_table instead of original BIG DB calls. that still benefit from cost :D

Comment: A for effort. What is meant by an explain though is sightly different. It's simply running the query by putting 'explain' in front of it. It shows the execution plan and helps you figure out why a query is slow

Comment: And how do I post an explain?

Comment: After reformat your SQL and I found out: 1. SQLs are very similar, you can think of merge two SQL into one. 2. OR is very dangerous, are you missing one () i.e. AND (members.username = :user OR ... )?

Comment: @e4c5 I am still trying. I apparently find SO to be a lot more difficult to use than you do - specifically when dealing with sql and table formatting and crap. This is the hardest system ever. None the less I am still formatting this explain command so I can actually output it on SO.

Comment: lol now you tell me!

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN :)

Comment: Can we split this into two questions? It's far too complex for one answer. I suggest that the first question (this) one concentrate on the performances of the queries. You already have two answers for that. Please post another question by cutting out the parts about running 35 queries. And please clarify by including your looping code etc about how exactly that happens.

Comment: While editing questions that invalidate answers are hugely frowned upon here. The editing I am suggesting will not invaildate the two answers you have at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your explain result, note the `possible_keys` column.

> The possible_keys column indicates which indexes MySQL can choose from
>   use to find the rows in this table ...   If this column is NULL (or
>   undefined in JSON-formatted output), there are no relevant indexes. In
>   this case, you may be able to improve the performance of your query by
>   examining the WHERE clause to check whether it refers to some column
>   or columns that would be suitable for indexing. If so, create an
>   appropriate index and check the query with EXPLAIN again.

It is likely that you will see a big boost in performance if you index friend1,friend2 fields on your list_friends table. Particularly in view of the fact that it's used twice.

```
ALTER TABLE list_friends ADD INDEX f1f2(friend1,friend2)
```

You *may* also benefit from an index on the `time` field on your favorite table.

These operations will make each of your queries run faster, as for the need to run them 35 times, it's not clear why you are actually running them 7 times and on 5 different databases.

Comment: Awesome suggestions. I have rewritten the queries a bit to completely remove the UNION and replaced it with a second OR members.username IN clause as the UNION was entirely null. Both friend1 and friend2 fields are indexed, but they don't appear that way unless I run a direct wuery on them vs a subquery. I am puzzled by that.

Comment: As to why I need to run the queries 35 times, thats easy to explain. Each query grabs the number of "something" performed by a user and their friends over each day for the past week. So we get a number for all a friends "Favorites" for the past 1, then 2 days ago, then 3, etc. up to 7. Then we do the same to find out how many banners they added to the system, how many comments they have made, etc. We then use these numbers to create a graph chart of "stream activity" for the past 7 days in each of 5 categories.

Comment: Mysql isn't so good at subqueries like M$ SQL or Postgresql. usually when a subquery is re written as a join you get a huge boost in performance. In fact at a glance I feel it might be possible with yours

Comment: Those 35 iterations, or at least the first part of it may be reducable to one by  further joins combined wtih group by

Comment: I have rewritten my queries many different ways and the mysql performance pages kind of indicate that you simply have to test with benchmarks because at times sub-queries are faster and other times joins are.However I am finding the best solution is as I originally thought with is to either to write the data to a cookie or to a session and update it once an hour. Makes it so users are not all loading the data at the same time, or on each page load. Only if the cookie/session information has expired.

Comment: Yes, Mysql documentation tries to gloss over their subquery poor performance :). Yes, sessions would work and maybe memcache and/or redis might also help

Comment: so how did it go?

Comment: The only way we could find to maintain server load for these particular queries was storing data in cookies and calling at random intervals with updates. Even the best written queries were still compounding into crazy amounts of calls.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT datediff(NOW(), `stream_updates`.`time`) AS days, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM stream_updates 
INNER JOIN members ON members.username = stream_updates.username 
WHERE datediff(NOW(), `stream_updates`.`time`) < 3
AND (
  members.username = :user
  OR
  members.username IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT if(friend2 = :user, friend1, friend2)
    FROM list_friends 
    WHERE friend1 = :user
    OR friend2 = :user
  )
)
GROUP BY 1
```

Keywords Distinct might speedup as well

And here is the update to your demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa369f6/7

OR run this, pick up whichever is faster:

```
SELECT datediff(NOW(), `stream_updates`.`time`) AS days, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM stream_updates 
INNER JOIN members ON members.username = stream_updates.username 
WHERE datediff(NOW(), `stream_updates`.`time`) < 3
AND (
  members.username = :user
  OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM list_friends WHERE
    (members.username = friend1 AND friend2 = :user)
    OR 
    (members.username = friend2 AND friend1 = :user)
  )
)
GROUP BY 1
```